# Order and storage space, what relation?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony3.x

I do not know what relationship to use for this application: Many orders can have the same storage space, and one storage space can refer to many orders.I tried Many-To-Many, Unidirectional and One-To-Many, Bidirectional but using such a solution for another table e.g payment status.

I get the error

```
The mappings AppBundle \ Entity \ ... and AppBundle \ Entity \ ... are inconsistent with each other.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIU you're trying to describe a one-to-many relationship: `Order (*)-----(1) StorageSpace`

If so, this is the piece of documentation you're looking for: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

This will result in something like the following mapping :

```
/** @ORM\Entity */
class Order
{
    //...

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StorageSpace", inversedBy="orders") */
    private $storageSpace;
}

/** @ORM\Entity */
class StorageSpace
{
    //...

    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Order", mappedBy="storageSpace") */
    private $orders;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->orders = new ArrayCollection;
    }
}
```